# Android Application crash Issue

Tags: java, android

I am new to android and working on real simple application. I've declared some strings array in `String.xml` and displaying those string on Text View one by one.User can change the strings on press of "Next" and "Previous" buttons.

**Problem i am facing:**

1. First String is not getting displayed when application is launched
2. When all string are finished and still next button is pressed, application crashes.

MainActivity.java

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            final String allquotes[] = getResources()
                    .getStringArray(R.array.quotes);
            counter = 0;
            display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvdisplay);
            choosenext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bnext);

            choosenext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter++;
                    display.setText(allquotes[counter]);

                }
            });

            chooseprevious = (Button)findViewById(R.id.bprevious);
            chooseprevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                            display.setText(allquotes[counter]);

                }
            });


        }


    }
```

logcat

```
02-15 12:52:37.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(405): No keyboard for id 0
02-15 12:52:37.020: W/KeyCharacterMap(405): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-15 12:52:47.509: D/dalvikvm(405): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 54K, 52% free 2586K/5379K, external 2237K/2793K, paused 382ms
02-15 12:52:59.420: D/AndroidRuntime(405): Shutting down VM
02-15 12:52:59.420: W/dalvikvm(405): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.example.zzzz.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:34)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
02-15 12:52:59.431: E/AndroidRuntime(405):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvdisplay"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bprevious"
            android:layout_width="154dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/previous" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bnext"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/next" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post the logcat output

Comment: @GopalRao - for why is it not being displayed , in case the color, background is the same (?)

Comment: @GopalRao surprised that you didn't quesrtion the requirement of logcat , the crash reason is pretty evident without that actually

Answer (score 1):

1. You increment the counter before the text is set, so the allcounter index reffered to is 1 instead of 0.
2. Without the error log its hard to say what the problem may be. Use the logcat.

Comment: can u tell tell, like suppose, there were 10 string getting displayed and on 10th string user presses next, then how to display the 1st string of the app ?

Comment: Yes thats easy, 
            choosenext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    counter++;
                    if(counter==10){counter=0;}
                    display.setText(allquotes[counter]);
                }
            });

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
        choosenext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter++;
                if (counter >= allquotes.length || counter < 0) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
                display.setText(allquotes[counter]);
            }
        });

        chooseprevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                if (counter < 0 || counter >= allquotes.length) {
                    counter = 0;
                }
                display.setText(allquotes[counter]);

            }
        });
```

Comment: like suppose, there were 10 string getting displayed and on 10th string user presses next, how to display the 1st string of the app ?

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not show the first string when the app launched. You can add `display.setText(allquotes[0]);` somewhere.
2. Add checking `if (counter < allquotes.length) display.setText(allquotes[counter]);`

Answer (score 0):

Well, the crash is an IndexOutOfBounds problem.  onClock increases counter.  If counter >= allquotes.length, the app will access an index out of the array and crash.  Change onClick to

```
            if(counter < allquotes.length-1){
                counter++;
            }
            display.setText(allquotes[counter]);
```

Answer (score 0):

For When all string are finished and still next button is pressed, application crashes,

Counter keeps incrementing and reaches a point where there is no value for that position in the String array.

What happens when you launch app and press previous button straightaway ?. The counter becomes (-1) then. Need to handle minimum and maximum values for the counter depending on the size of the Array.

Answer (score 0):

The application crashes with array out of bounds since you try to access  allquotes[Counter] when the counter value is larger then the array size.

Limit the counter or reset it back to zero when it reaches the array size will solve your problem.